# Does anyone know a demo JSON server?

Tags: json, testing, demo

I am building a library that makes calls to a server that returns JSON. I'd like to be able to test this library. This would require my testing code to make a call to a working server that returns JSON. Does anyone know of a server that is suitable for this purpose?

Comment: You can just create a simple a JSON file and put it on your local server.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is a great server located at http://echo.jsontest.com that does precisely this. You can even determine the output by changing the URI you call.

For example, the http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value URI returns this:

```
{"key": "value"}
```

And the http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/otherkey/othervalue URI returns:

```
{
   "otherkey": "othervalue",
   "key": "value"
}
```

The server is also very fast, ideal for testing purposes.

Comment: So, how what URL should I hit to test a POST call? Let's say I have a simple test POST call that send JSON in the body (and not in the URL) like this {"testing":"some value"}... how would I use jsontest to test this call?

Comment: @zumzum Just use the same URL but call it using a POST request.

Comment: Sorry for late comment, but do you know how to echo json with arrays of json objects?

Comment: @Cԃաԃ I'm sorry, I don't know how to do that.

Comment: http://echo.jsontest.com is over quota - stopped responding a while ago...can't find a suitable replacement

Comment: I created an alternative. If you want more features tweet me at @2upmedia, I'll work more on it. CORS-enabled. https://ajaxechoserver-2upmedia.rhcloud.com/

Comment: found this, which echoes the request as json: http://scooterlabs.com/echo.json
you can also add parameters to the request like:
http://scooterlabs.com/echo.json?name=harvey&surname=wallbanger

Answer (score 0):

You can test your lib with facebook or twitter public api. 
For exemple : 
`http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=blue%20angels` will return a json object.

Doc here : https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search

Comment: Twitter API v1 are now deprecated; the new v1.1 requires authentication, so no more "fire and forget"!